# WooCommerce - Get the product description by product_id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

How can I get the product description or the product object using product ID.

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_description = get_the_product_description($item['product_id']); // is there any method can I use to fetch the product description?
}
```

The code above extends class WC_Payment_Gateway

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: If your description is written in post content, use Vincent's answer; if your description is written in WooCommerce's product description field, use Raunak's answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $product_description = get_post($item['product_id'])->post_content; // I used wordpress built-in functions to get the product object 
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using WooCommerce `3.0` or above, then you can get *description* with the below code.

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_details = $product->get_data();

    $product_full_description = $product_details['description'];
    $product_short_description = $product_details['short_description'];
}
```

Alternate way (*recommended*)

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_instance = wc_get_product($product_id);

    $product_full_description = $product_instance->get_description();
    $product_short_description = $product_instance->get_short_description();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think, there is one line missing like $product = new WC_Product($product_id); I would also suggest to use the specific methods to ensure the hooks are executed:
$product_full_description = $product->get_description();
$product_short_description = $product->get_short_description();

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo wc_get_product( $post->ID )->get_short_description(); ?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't ideal. Could you add some context explaining what this code does and how it addresses OP's problem?

Comment: This answer is perfect, the context is in the title of the original question.