# How to programmatically grab the product description in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I saw this, [WooCommerce - Get the product description by product_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763915/woocommerce-get-the-product-description-by-product-id)

But I was hoping there was a shorter way to get the product by ID and get the description? Any idea?

I'm using WooCommerce 3.0 and above.

Comment: What do you mean by "shorter" way? That code is pretty short. Are you asking about how to get a description from products in an order or do you just want to get a product by ID and get the description? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, we don't know what do you mean by "GRAB"… It can be how to SET (or how to GET) the product description.

---

There is multiple ways to **SET** the product description.

1) From the product ID using Wordpress `wp_update_post()`;

```
  wp_update_post( array('ID' => $product_id, 'post_content' => 'This is the <strong>product description</strong> content.') );
```

2) From the `WC_Product` Object using `set_description()` method

```
// Get the WC_Product Object instance (optional if needed)
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Set the description
$product->set_description('This is the <strong>product description</strong> content.');

$product->save(); // Save product data
```

---

There is multiple ways to **GET** the product description (as explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763915/woocommerce-get-the-product-description-by-product-id)).

1) From the product ID, using Wordpress `get_post()` function:

```
 $product_description = get_post( $product_id )->post_content;
```

2) From the `WC_Product` Object using `get_description()` method

```
// Get the WC_Product Object instance (optional if needed)
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Get the product description
$description = $product->get_description();
```